# Unresolved external symbols with Boost

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking

I am trying to compile the Boost.Regex program from the [Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/windows.html), but even though I am linking the required libraries, I am getting some unresolved external symbols:

> ```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
> 1>  main.cpp
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::re_detail_106100::raw_storage::resize(unsigned int)" (?resize@raw_storage@re_detail_106100@boost@@QAEXI@Z) referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall boost::re_detail_106100::raw_storage::extend(unsigned int)" (?extend@raw_storage@re_detail_106100@boost@@QAEPAXI@Z)
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void * __thiscall boost::re_detail_106100::raw_storage::insert(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?insert@raw_storage@re_detail_106100@boost@@QAEPAXII@Z) referenced in function "public: struct boost::re_detail_106100::re_syntax_base * __thiscall boost::re_detail_106100::basic_regex_creator<char,struct boost::regex_traits<char,class boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::insert_state(int,enum boost::re_detail_106100::syntax_element_type,unsigned int)" (?insert_state@?$basic_regex_creator@DU?$regex_traits@DV?$cpp_regex_traits@D@boost@@@boost@@@re_detail_106100@boost@@QAEPAUre_syntax_base@23@HW4syntax_element_type@23@I@Z)
> 1>C:\Users\unknown\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

Here is the code (taken from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)):

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat("^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)");

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Some information:

- This happens under Debug and Release
- I can't build the project under x64, because the libraries are x86
- I built the static library using `bootstrap`, then `b2`
- I included `libboost_regex-vc140-mt-1_61.lib` (`libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib` for Debug)
- Not using Unicode character set (in Visual Studio project properties)
- I am using Visual Studio 2015
- I am using Boost 1.61
- This happens for *every* Boost code that requires a library
- This obviously doesn't happen for header only Boost libraries

Any ideas?

Comment: This link http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2010/04/57957.php suggests that there is some difference in the compiler flags between building the boost libraries and your project

Comment: @MirceaBaja You don't know how happy I am :) Thank you very much, if you want to, post it as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2010/04/57957.php suggests that there is some difference in the compiler flags between building the boost libraries and your project